# Getting a "zenity, kdialog, Xdialog missing" Error when trying to run an appimage

Tags: appimage

I am trying to run the EdexUI app image https://github.com/GitSquared/edex-ui/releases
After making it into an executable I try to run it but it gives me the following error:

```
zenity, kdialog, Xdialog missing. Skipping /tmp/.mount_eDEX-UzH142J/AppRun.
/tmp/.mount_eDEX-UzH142J/edex-ui: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out what exactly that error means or how to fix it.

Could you help me fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another error message in the topic of your question and another one in the text.

Regarding the message from topic, looks like application displays dialog boxes using one of the default system tools that provide this feature. These tools are usually pre-installed in various desktop environments: `zenity` in GNOME or MATE, `kdialog` in KDE and `Xdialog` should be probably available in other DEs (I'm not sure about this one). For some reason, none of these utilities is present on your system, so the solution is to install one of them.

Regarding the message from text, `libnss3` package seems to be missing, so you have to install it.

Comment: My bad, it seems I didn't paste the whole error. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: So you probably need to install both zenity/kdialog/Xdialog (according to your DE) and libnss3.

Comment: Installing the packages fixed the errors. Thanks!